# returning zip for download from view in django

Tags: django, zip

I try to download a zip file in my Django application.

How should I return it from the view?

I tried the code below, but I get some kind of alert in the browser with the content of the file inside my zip.

What am I doing wrong?

```
def download_logs(request):
    date = datetime.datetime.now().__str__().replace(" ", "_").split(".")[0]
    os.system("df -h . > /tmp/disk_space")
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=logs_%s.zip' % date

    files = []
    files.append("/tmp/disk_space")
    buffer = StringIO()
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for name in files:
        file = open(name, "r")
        zip.writestr(name, file.read())
        file.close()
    zip.close()
    buffer.flush()

    ret_zip = buffer.getvalue()
    buffer.close()
    response.write(ret_zip)
    return response
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should tell the browser to treat the response as a file attachment.

From the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment), you should do something like:

```
>> response = HttpResponse(my_data, mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
>>> response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=foo.xls'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to actual working code for building a ZipFile in memory and returning it to the user as a file to download: [django-rosetta's view.py](http://code.google.com/p/django-rosetta/source/browse/trunk/rosetta/views.py#254)