# django zip file doesn't get downloaded

Tags: django, download

I want to download zip files using `Django views`. I have gone through many solutions in stack overflow. But the file does not get downloaded at all. Here is the code I am using.

Could anyone, tell me where I am going wrong.

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % doc[Zip_file_name]
response['X-Sendfile'] = "./Zipfiles" # the path where the zip files are stored
return response
```

In `chrome`, If I use `inspect element`, and double click on the `url` shown in the `network` tab, the file gets downloaded as it is recognized as a `http` get request, whereas on `button click` nothing happens.

Please Help.

Comment: Refer to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935014/returning-zip-for-download-from-view-in-django

Comment: thanks...i tried that also...din't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper

# file
response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(myfile), content_type='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myfile.zip'
return response
```

Comment: if the zip files are present in a different location..i should pass the path to FileWrapper right??

Comment: I get this error - ERROR - 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'
FileWrapper can be used directly for zip files??
and if I put FileWrapper(open(myFile))...in the response it just displays the individual file names which have been zipped...

Comment: `download_url =  "./Zipfiles/" + doc[Zip_file_name]
response=HttpResponse(FileWrapper(open(download_url)),content_type='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=%s' %doc[Zip_file_name]`

Comment: I did not put download url in my codes. Perhaps you could change filename to your filename_location. response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename_path'

Comment: this is the response I see if i print it out on the terminal..  

    Content-Type: application/zip
    Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=V_Cisco_Alpha_1357884000.0_1360562400.0.zip

P?KB0V_Cisco_Alpha_1357884000.0_1360562400.0_info.txtP?KB0??V_Cisco_Alpha_1357884000.0_1360562400.0_info.txtPK^P
`

Comment: oh..ok..so i just pass the filename in FileWrappper??

Comment: Don't do that, don't you have variable for your filename_path?

Comment: that is stored in download_url...  its a relative path  download_url="./ZipFiles" + doc[Zip_file_name]

Comment: we will talk later, I will first eat my dinner